# Inlined Webpack JS file doesn't work

Tags: javascript, webpack, vue.js

I have a webpack project (based on https://github.com/vuejs/vue-webpack-example) which generates an index.html file and a javascript file containing the application.

Everything works fine when I include the JavaScript like this:

```
<script src="static/js/app.js"></script>
```

When I try to include the contents of static/js/app.js directly in a script tag (because we need to end up with a single .html file) it doesn't work anymore. It looks like the javascript doesn't get exectuted at all:

```
<script>!function(e){function t(i){if(n[i])return...</script>
```

I extracted the application into 3 files (manifest.js, vendor.js and app.js) where vendor.js contains the libraries I need from node_modules. It works as long as I don't include vendor.js directly. So I can inline the manifest.js and app.js but not vendor.js.

Any ideas why the inlined js doesn't work but the included js via an url does work? Until now I thought js would behave exactly the same, no matter how it's included.

Comment: If the in-lined script is the same as that in the file it will work the same. Can you include the last part of the script in your post? Like `<script>!function(e){...}(whatever_you_are_passing_in)</script>`

Comment: Yeah, that's what I expected. The file is over 1mb, because it's a complete vue.js application and I can't share it here. I expect there to be a small difference in handling of these files. Maybe there are some js functions which behave differently/don't work when included directly?

Comment: Just do as I asked in the comment above... that will help to understand how the function should be executed. We don't need to see what's between the {}

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood you. Here is the link to the vendor.js file: https://gist.github.com/Sopamo/f2a591b4afaa91238516b82006e85845
As the other files work fine the error must be somewhere in this file.
Edit3...: I want to emphasize that the vendor.js file is a generated file which just contains npm libraries.

Comment: I realized what's going on. There are <script> tags inside of the vendor.js which are used like document.write("<script>...</script>"). I can't change that obviously. Is there a way to be able to keep the script tags inside of the script tag?

Comment: so you in-lined the bundle? it doesn't look like it from your example above...

Comment: What do you mean? I took the contents of the js file and placed it inside a script tag. Well.. Exactly like you would inline a js file, there is just that one way to do it :)

Comment: Ok. It's probably just me but the reason I ask is because the bundle looks like `webpackJsonp([1,0],[,function(e,t,n){(...` and that's not what you have in your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out what's wrong.

Some browsers (I tested Safari and Chrome on Mac) seem to not like `<script>` tags which have an opening script tag somewhere inside them. Even though all the closing script tags are escaped (like `document.write("</script"+">")`)

Strangely this does work in simple example like this one:

```
<script>
    document.write("<script>alert(1)</script"+">")
</script>
```

In complex examples (like this one: https://gist.github.com/Sopamo/f2a591b4afaa91238516b82006e85845)
it only works when all `<script>` tags are "escaped". Maybe someone can find out what's the difference between the simple and the complex example.

In my case I used the inline example of the [html-webpack-plugin](https://github.com/ampedandwired/html-webpack-plugin/tree/master/examples/inline) which I modified as follows:

```
script(type="text/javascript") !{compilation.assets[jsFile.substr(htmlWebpackPlugin.files.publicPath.length)].source().replace(/<script>/g,'<script"+">')}
```

Note the replace() call at the end.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't need to include the app.js file. If you run `npm run build` from project folder it will create all files needed to run the application inside the `dist` folder.

Remember also that the app must be served from an **HTTP server** in order to work.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I think you overlooked the problem I had. I need to get a single html file without any js/css file and therefore want to inline the files (manually or via a build script - it doesn't matter). That's the problem, because the js files doesn't work anymore when inlined.